# How to insert names into 2D char array from file

Tags: c++

I am programming student and my teacher has told to me to store some names from file into 2D char array. Now I know it is easy by string but my teacher has limited me to use cstring only.

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream> 
#include<cstring>
int main()
{
char names[5][50];
int row=0,col=0,x=0; 
ifstream input("file.txt");

while(input.good())
{
    input.getline(names[row],50);
    row++;
    cout<<names;        
}
input.close();
return 0;
```

}

it is giving garbage value.
This is my input file:

- Aasim nadeem
- talha arif
- naeem tahir
- ahmad saleem
- saleem athar

Comment: What do you mean by "garbage value"?  What do you expect to see when you try to print an entire 2D array?

Comment: If the line you are reading from the file is less than 50, then the rest of the array are garbage.

Comment: @FirstStep yes but it should show names at first then garbage but it isn't showing any name
The output is 0x246fe04 repeatedly

Comment: What happens if instead you do `cout<<names[row-1];`?

Comment: @ScottHunter it is ignoring last name Saleem Athar.

Comment: @AasimN.Liaqat: I don't know what that means, but it sounds much less dire than your original description, suggesting the insertions are fine but you went about printing them wrong.

Comment: if it printed all of them except Saleem Athar, means it didn't print junk? Where are we? I don't get you

Comment: Can you tell if it *tried* to read the last name?

Comment: how to check that... I am sorry I am pretty noob.

Comment: Step Over your code using F-10, statement by statement and hoover your mouse on variables to see its values

Comment: I am using notepad++ I don't know how to do that in it 
@FirstStep

Comment: Me neither. Google it.

Comment: okay what I did is cout<<row; 
and it showed me that my loop while(input.good()) iterated 5 times.

Comment: @ScottHunter okay it worked thanks for the Help :)

Comment: @FirstStep it is working now thanks for the Help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cout<<names;` appears to be trying to print the whole 2D array, but `cout` doesn't know how to, so treats it as an address and prints just that.  If instead you try and print individual names (i.e. `out<<names[row-1];`), these are character pointers, so it *does* know how to print them.